# How to import a service from another module using angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the user from my LoginService to profile module. My profile module have 3 components. Loginservice is in another component inside the AppModule. 
This is the method to get user in login.service.ts:

```
getCurrentUser() {
    return this._storage.get<User>(this.USER_KEY);
  }// End getCurrentUser ()
```

This is my app.module.ts:

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/SharedModule';
import 'hammerjs';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout/flexbox";

import { LocalStorageModule } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './modules/login/login.component';
import { Angular2RoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { KeysPipe } from './pipes/keys.pipe';
import { AdminComponent } from './modules/admin/admin.component';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './modules/admin/admin-home/admin-home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './modules/profile/profile.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Angular2RoutingModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    FlexLayoutModule,
    LocalStorageModule.withConfig({
      prefix: 'rsm',
      storageType: 'localStorage'
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my profile.module.ts:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { profileRouting } from './profile.routing';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';
import { ProfileHomeComponent } from './profile-home/profile-home.component';
import { ProfileSecurityComponent } from './profile-security/profile-security.component';
import { ProfileSettingsComponent} from './profile-settings/profile-settings.component';
import { FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout/flexbox';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ProfileComponent,
        ProfileHomeComponent,
        ProfileSecurityComponent,
        ProfileSettingsComponent, 
    ],

    imports: [profileRouting, CommonModule, MaterialModule.forRoot(),FlexLayoutModule],
    providers: [],
})
export class ProfileModule {

}
```

How i use that method in loginservice inside the component in profilemodule?

Comment: Have you tried to add the login service as a provider in the AppModule?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers

Comment: Yes.But when i add the login service as a provider in the appModule it gives this Error.Error: Type LoginComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ProfileModule! Please consider moving LoginComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and ProfileModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoginComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and ProfileModule.

Comment: It is my mistake. I imported logincomponent inside the profilemodule. I forgot to delete it. garth74 is correct.It works when i add the login service as a provider in the AppModule. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start by separating login from application module. Create login module.

Now, since you want to use something from entirely different module. You will need to import that module.

So, you should

- import login module in profile module
- import login service in profile component

and that should do it.

It's like importing HttpModule and then importing Http service before using them.